# Comparing two input fields - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Forgive me but I'm just starting to learn Javascript. I'm trying to get the sum of two input fields, and I'd like to update the result "live" so to speak, on every keyup event.

At the moment the result field just disappears when values are entered into the input fields.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much,

Peter

edit: how stupid of me, I forgot to post the code

http://jsfiddle.net/u7VwP/

```
var inputFirst = $('#first'),
    inputSecond = $('#second'),
    inputFirstVal = inputFirst.val(),
    inputSecondVal = inputSecond.val();

function getResult(first, second) {
 var result = first + second;
 $('p#result').text(result);
};


inputFirst.on('keyup', function() {
 getResult(inputFirstVal, inputSecondVal);
});
inputSecond.on('keyup', function() {
 getResult(inputFirstVal, inputSecondVal);
});​
```

Comment: If you post your code we can help you identify the problem.

Comment: Actually, it's hard to tell without any example code.

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: You know what would be helpful? Code.

Comment: Are you trying to add to two values together? or just append the values? The val() function is only running once. You will need to get the val() each time you call the `getResult` function

Answer (score 1):

```
inputFirstVal = inputFirst.val(),
inputSecondVal = inputSecond.val();
```

These variables are only initialized once. You need to call `val()` at the exact moment when you want to read the current value.

See http://jsfiddle.net/u7VwP/7/

Updated: Added `parseInt` so you'd be adding numbers not strings.

Note this syntax:

```
first = parseInt(first) || 0;
```

If the result of `parseInt` is falsy (like `NaN` "not a number" when we cannot parse the number, or a literal 0), the value is defaulted to the right hand-side of `||` operator, 0.

Answer (score 0):

As from my comment, the getResult function would end as:

```
function getResult() {
 inputFirstVal = inputFirst.val(),
 inputSecondVal = inputSecond.val();
 var result = inputFirstVal  + inputSecondVal ;
 $('p#result').text(result);
};
```

as on change you would just call the function:

```
inputFirst.on('keyup', getResult);
inputSecond.on('keyup', getResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputFirst = $('#first'),
    inputSecond = $('#second'),
    inputFirstVal = inputFirst.val(),
    inputSecondVal = inputSecond.val();

function getResult(first, second) {
    var result = (parseInt(first) || 0) + (parseInt(second) || 0);
    //field.val() returns strings not numbers so parsing to ints. If letter is passed, consider it as 0
    $('p#result').text(result);
};

function handler()
{
  getResult(inputFirst.val() || 0, inputSecond.val() || 0); 
  // if value is null or undefined pass 0 to the function
}

inputFirst.on('keyup', handler);
inputSecond.on('keyup', handler);​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputFirst = $('#first'),
    inputSecond = $('#second');

function getResult() {
    var result = (parseInt(inputFirst.val()) || 0) + (parseInt(inputSecond.val()) || 0);
    $('#result').text(result);
};

inputFirst.on('keyup', function() {
    getResult();
});
inputSecond.on('keyup', function() {
    getResult();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to read & think about the runtime of Javascript code. In your example, the variables get read out when the input fields are empty. So for that, they'll always be empty. You've to read them out in the function where you add them together.

Additionally I'd recommend to have a look at the jQuery selectors. In the following code, a bind is made for two objects.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#first, #second').bind('keyup', function() {
        $('#result').val($('#first').val() + $('#second').val());
    });
});
```